# ConcurrentModificationException when adding to ArrayList in getter

Tags: java, list, arraylist, concurrency, concurrentmodification

The following code gives a ConcurrentModificationException, particular the escaped lines and I'm wondering why.
I have found that this can happen when you add to a list after an iterator has been extraced or when two threads access the list at the same time. However I don't think this is the case in my example.

What I am doing is passing the GameObjects list as a parameter:

```
camera.render(g, map.getGameObjectHandler().getGameObjects());
```

Getter:

```
    public ArrayList<GameObject> getGameObjects() {
//          if (player != null) {
//              gameObjects.add(player);
//          }
        return this.gameObjects;
```

I am later iterating over the listbut not removing or adding anything.
I'm only accesing each element after another using an Iterator.

I hope that I provided enough information and will gladly provide more if needed.

Thanks in advance.

//EDIT:

I think the problem was adding the player to the list each time the getter is called. I fixed it by adding the player to the list when he is spawned.
But I would still like to know what I did wrong, because this isn't
the root of the problem or is it ?

//Update:

The main loop looks basically like this:

```
map.update(); // iterating over the list and calling methods of objects in 
              // the list [running in main game thread]

repaint(); // calling paintComponentMethod where we pass our list as an 
           // argument so all its content can be drawn [running in event-
           // dispatch-thread !?]`
```

Comment: Were you adding to the list while the iterator was iterating?

Comment: Probably that was the problem. If you provide some code that was adding players, it probably will be more clear. And also you can put some breakpoints in `ArrayList` and `AbstractList` classes everywhere where `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` happens when you're iterating over a collection and you modify it. It's pretty straight-forward and there aren't exceptions to that. Either don't do that, or make a copy of the collection to iterate over.

Comment: Where are you adding the players to the list?  Is that done in another thread?  You need to show more code for us to help.

Answer (score 0):

ConcurrentModificationException on an ArrayList can happen when:

- a portion of code is both iterating and modifying the list,
- there are concurrent modifications like add / remove while another thread is iterating on the list.

Comment: Pleae take a look at the main post. under update 2 i posted where i am using the list and that is where i think the problem is.

Because both calls are executed after another i thought that i could get away with doing it this way.
What could be a possible solution to this problem ?
Maybe creating a copy of said arraylist for the render method ?

Comment: Can you try to pass it an immutable list (from guava) and see if it breaks? IF yes, then the render() call is mutating the list. If not, then you have multithreaded access to this list.